# Launch Android application from default system webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, dd-wrt, coovachilli

I had created Captive portal which works very well and on connect with my wifi device it gives system generated notification using WISPR request which will open in system webview. On opening this redirected url i want to launch my application which is already installed in my device.

I found many blogs for launching application from google chrome using below code url

intent://host/#Intent;scheme=http;package=my package name ;S.browser_fallback_url=playstore url ;end

But this works only in Google chrome and i want this in default system webview.

Does any method exists that can help me to launch the app from web view??

Is there any workaround to solve this problem?? How can i fix this issue??

Can We stop WISPr Reuest from DD-WRT for smart user application ?

For creating captive portal i have used TP-Link Router(DD-WRT Firmware),Chillispot,Free radius server,Dalo admin.

Please Help.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about deep-links https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

And here is ready service for them https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/